# How can I persist a jQuery.hover popup on mouse over the popup

Tags: jquery, popup, hover

this is  my issue: when mouse move over a item ,there is a popup to show the detail of the item. I use hover() to do this(I set a  function to delay trig). But, when I moveout the item and moveover the detail popup. the popup just disappear. So , how to keep the popup when when the mouse not hover the trig element, but hover the popup .this is my code

tab.find("tr").slice(1,parseInt(jQuery( "#itemCount").val())+2).find("td").mouseDelay(500).hover(function (e){

```
    var id=jQuery(this).parent().find( "td:first").html();
    var url = "/" +job.webDatabasePath+"/DPGetDoc?openAgent&id="+id;

    jQuery.ajax( {
               url:url,
              success: function(data){
                    var xmlObj = jQuery(data);
                     var major = xmlObj.find("DPTrainSubItem" ).text();
                    jQuery( "#blockDeptName").val(major);                                    
                     }     
              } )
              var a=getMousePoint(e);
           if((parseInt(document.getElementById("popupContact").style.width)+a.x)<parseInt(document.body.clientWidth)){
              jQuery( "#popupContact").css({
                "top": a.y+20,
                "left": a.x+20
               });
             popupModal.show();
            }else{
                jQuery( "#popupContact").css({
                    "top": a.y+20,
                    "left": a.x-parseInt(document.getElementById("popupContact").style.width)-50
                 });
                 popupModal.show(); 
              }
    },
   function (){

    if(jQuery('#popupContact').is(':hover')){
        disablePopup();
        }
 });
```

if the jQuery('#popupContact').is(':hover') is work in IE, my job is easy. however it's not. So what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using a settimeout, as follows:

```
setTimeout(function (){$("#popupContact").remove();}, 3000);
```

Hope this helps